# Fantasy novel about magic and telepathic birds

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, telepathy

I am looking for a book I read back in high school. This was 2003 so it was published before then. I only remember a few things.

Only a few people were able to have a bond with one bird. But there was one of the characters that had two birds. Those birds changed his moods. Their magic was outlawed or something like that. There's a group of people and they need to find something to defeat the person in charge.

I remember the book cover had some light blue in the background.
This is all I can remember. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Aside from the presence of magic and telepathy, was this set in something resembling the present day real world, or did it take place in more of a historical setting?

Comment: The Mercedes Lackey Valdemar books have the Hawkbrothers, who are generally bonded to birds of prey, although I don't particularly remember anyone having two birds, or that being forbidden.

Comment: If I remember correctly, it was set in the midevil Era. It was not Mercedes Lackey. Only birds were telepathic. But thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Is this ***[Children of Amarid](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/355078.Children_of_Amarid)*** (1998) by David B. Coe, the first book in the *[Lon Tobyn Chronicle](https://www.goodreads.com/series/52894-lon-tobyn-chronicle)* trilogy...?

The plot involves an order of mages with hawk familiars, and the cover of the first book does have a light blue background. The antagonist is apparently a former member of the order who was expelled for abusing his power.

> **A thousand years ago in Tobyn-Ser, Amarid and Theron discovered magical crystals that enabled them to bond with hawks to produce powerful magic. together, they started an order, dedicating themselves to using their powers to help their people. Theron was expelled from the Order for abusing his power, but ever since, the Children of Amarid have faithfully upheld their vow using their power selflessly to protect the land and its people.**
>
> Now the idyllic peace of Tobyn-Ser has been shattered by news of mages destroying crops, burning villages, and murdering innocents. Rumor even say that Theron may have returned from the dead to wreak vengeance on Tobyn-Ser an the Order that spurned him.
>
> uncovering the truth about the renegade mages and restoring peace to the sundered land will take a young but powerful Hawk-Mage named Jaryd across the length and breadth of Tobyn-Ser, a journey he must complete before it's too late to save the Order...and the world.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Children of Amarid" (1998) by David B. Coe.]

In a [blog](http://shera-bookwhispers.blogspot.com/2016/11/guest-post-giveaway-david-b-coe.html), the author of the book commented on the "psychic bond" between the mages and their avian familiars.

> **The mages in my LonTobyn books draw their magic from avian familiars -- birds of prey with whom they share a psychic bond.** This bond allows them to draw on the power within the birds to heal, to do battle and protect themselves, and to cast a host of other spells. The birds themselves are characters in the stories, and to this day people who can’t remember any of the titles will talk to me about how much they loved the books by saying “You know: the ones with the hawks and owls.”

Comment: Thank you. But that one is not it.